# Howto avoid autostart of iOS app?

Tags: ios, applications, startup, reboot

I use an iOS app that autostarts whenever I reboot the phone. How can I disable that ?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you told us which app it is

Comment: I'm looking for a generic way that I can use to disable any appstore app from autostarting.

Comment: Since this question is quite vague, I gave a general answer. Feel free to show more of your work - detailing what exactly makes you think an app "auto starts" if my guess in the answer was incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

In general, an iOS app is stateless.

Whether it's running or not, only the core iOS scheduler knows if a process is loaded into RAM and running or paused, suspended, or "frozen" to storage.

If you are referring to the list of icons that show in the multitasking bar - that too is stateless. All the programs that have been run show up in that list - even if you haven't run them yet on this boot. In fact, that list is backed up and restored onto a new device, so you could have an app appear in the multitasking bar that **has never run ever on that device**.